# How to Pass Async data to Android Widget

Tags: android, twitter, asynchronous, widget

Below is my RSS Parser in Application. Now I want the same data to be inserted in Widget Class so that i can show RSS Feeds into widget as well. Can someone show me how to pass those application data into my widget listview. Below are the Application and Widget Classes.

Note : I will be replacing "heading" and "content" variables in ListProvider.java to show my data there. Let me know if someone needs more classes which i can post if required to refer.

For Example : imageAndTexts1.get(position).getPubDate() will contain date from RSS Feeds. How can i pass this in String in ListProvider.java ??

TwitterFeeds.java

```
public class TwitterFeeds extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

ListView _rssFeedListView;
List<JSONObject> jobs;
List<RssFeedStructure> rssStr;
private TwitterAdapter _adapter;
TextView textview;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);
    _rssFeedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rssfeed_listview);
    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loading);
    RssFeedTask rssTask = new RssFeedTask();
    rssTask.execute();
}

public class RssFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    // private String Content;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog;
    String response = "";

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            String feed = "http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533944/index.rss";
            XmlHandler rh = new XmlHandler();
            rssStr = rh.getLatestArticles(feed);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return response;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (rssStr != null) {
            _adapter = new TwitterAdapter(TwitterFeeds.this, rssStr);
            _rssFeedListView.setAdapter(_adapter);
            textview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            _rssFeedListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "TwitterFeeds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
        }


    }

}
}
```

TwitterAdapter.java

```
public class TwitterAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RssFeedStructure> {
List<RssFeedStructure> imageAndTexts1 = null;
Context context;
public static String passtitletowidget; 


public TwitterAdapter(Activity activity,List<RssFeedStructure> imageAndTexts) {
    super(activity, 0, imageAndTexts);
    imageAndTexts1 = imageAndTexts;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    context = getContext();
    Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.twitteradapter, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.feed_text);
    TextView timeFeedText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.feed_updatetime);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.feed_image);
    try {

        passtitletowidget = imageAndTexts1.get(position).getTitle();

        Log.d("rssfeed", "imageAndTexts1.get(position).getImgLink() :: " + imageAndTexts1.get(position).getImgLink() + " :: " + imageAndTexts1.get(position).getTitle());

        //Underline HashTags -- To identify Mentioned user name; use this "@([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)"
        SpannableString hashtagintitle = new SpannableString(imageAndTexts1.get(position).getTitle());
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)").matcher(hashtagintitle);
        while (matcher.find())
        {
            hashtagintitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);

        }
        textView.setText(hashtagintitle);
        timeFeedText.setText(imageAndTexts1.get(position).getPubDate());

        //Underline Date
        /*SpannableString content = new SpannableString(imageAndTexts1.get(position).getPubDate());
        content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, 13, 0);
        timeFeedText.setText(content);*/


        if (imageAndTexts1.get(position).getImgLink() != null) {

            URL feedImage = new URL(imageAndTexts1.get(position)
                    .getImgLink().toString());
            if (!feedImage.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) feedImage
                        .openConnection();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(img);
            } else {
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rss_tab_tweets);
            }
        }

        //Share Button
        Button Button1= (Button)  rowView.findViewById(R.id.sharebutton);
        Button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        { 
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) 
               {
                    //Share Data
                    String shareBody = imageAndTexts1.get(position).getDescription();
                    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, shareBody));
                    //Share Data ends
               }

        });
        //Share Button ends

        //OpenWith Button
        Button Button2= (Button)  rowView.findViewById(R.id.openwith);
        Button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        { 
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) 
               {
                    //OpenWith Data
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    // We have to set data for our new Intent
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(imageAndTexts1.get(position).getLink()));
                    // And start activity with our Intent
                    context.startActivity(i);
                    //OpenWith Data ends
               }

        });
        //OpenWith Button ends

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    return rowView;

}
}
```

ListProvider.java

```
public class ListProvider implements RemoteViewsFactory {
private ArrayList<ListItem> listItemList = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
private Context context = null;
private int appWidgetId;

public ListProvider(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

    populateListItem();
}

private void populateListItem() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
        listItem.heading = "Heading" + i;
        listItem.content = i
                + " This is the content of the app widget listview.Nice content though";
        listItemList.add(listItem);
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listItemList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

/*
 *Similar to getView of Adapter where instead of View
 *we return RemoteViews 
 * 
 */
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    final RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(
            context.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_row);
    ListItem listItem = listItemList.get(position);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.heading, listItem.heading);
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.content, listItem.content);

    return remoteView;
}


@Override
public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
}

@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To support a `ListView` in an app widget, you will need to create a `RemoteViewsFactory` as a replacement for your `ListAdapter`, plus a `RemoteViewsService` to allow the app widget to talk to that factory. You will then be able to "bind" the `ListView` to the service, and the app widget framework will then be able to populate the `ListView`.

This is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections), and [here is another sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget) showing the use of a `ListView` in an app widget.

Comment: Thanks, all those things are implemented but in a static way. Now only thing i was looking for was to just get those feeds into Widget Class so that i need not to write same wrapper again.

Comment: @user574639: You have no choice but "to write same wrapper again". This is no different than how you need to work with a `RemoteViews` for the app widget itself instead of standard widgets as you do in an activity.

Comment: I got that. If you come across any sample tutorial in which specifically RSS Parsing is made for Android widgets then let me know. Thanks for your help

Comment: hi can you help me here's mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39587137/how-to-get-the-clicked-item-from-listview-of-a-widget-android i can't pass the data to another activity.